# MySQL Syntax Error, (1064)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

So i'm having this problem with my php script, that sends data from a HTML form to the database. Every time i try to use the form, i get the following error:

> Error: 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '', test.com' )' at line 1

```
<form method="post" action="">
<p>The title of what users will see(Eg. "MineVoxel - Great minecraft server", or "My cat blog - Go visit now!") </p>
    <input name="name" type="text">
<br>
<p>Name of the service type(Eg. Minecraft Server, Website, etc.)</p>
<br>
        <input name="service" type="text">
<br>
<p>Description of your website/service</p>
<br>
        <input name="description" type="text">
<br>
<p>A link or IP address to your service</p>
<br>
        <input name="address" type="text">
<br>
<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>

<?php
// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'CENSORED', 'CENSORED', 'CENSORED', 'CENSORED' );

  // Check our connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }


// remove old stale data
$sql = "DELETE FROM user
       WHERE ts_created < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 HOUR)";

if ( ! $mysqli->query($sql) ) {
    // log $mysqli->error somewhere
}




  // Insert our data
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user ( name, service, description, address ) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['service'])}', {$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description'])}', {$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['address'])}' )";
  $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

  // Print response from MySQL
  if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
  } else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
  }

  // Close our connection
  $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place single quotes around

```
)}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['address'])}'
    ^^^                                                      ^^^
```

Comment: Whoops! Missed that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a single quote missing:

```
])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description'])}',
     ^^^
```

You should learn about prepared statements.